# Hibernate saveOrUpdate Not working with Dynamic mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dynamic, hibernate-mapping

I am using [Hibernate dynamic modeling](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/dynamic_model.html) for persisting my objects. The issue i am facing right now is it is throwing exception when i am calling saveOrUpdate function. The exception is

```
2020-07-08 23:14:06 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:137 - SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2020-07-08 23:14:06 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:142 - Duplicate entry 'TYUTQ-2020-07-08 20:19:53' for key 'PRIMARY'
2020-07-08 23:14:06 ERROR ExceptionMapperStandardImpl:39 - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

When object is going to insert first time, it will successfully inserted but when object is already present in the database then saveOrUpdate method again call the **insert** method. I verified by using SHOW_SQL = "true" property.

The question is why it is not calling the **update** method?

Hibernate mapping file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
   <class entity-name="myTable">
      <composite-id>
         <key-property name="code" column="code" type="java.lang.String" />
         <key-property name="datetime" column="datetime" type="java.sql.Timestamp" />
      </composite-id>
      <property name="A" column="A_colummn" type="java.math.BigDecimal" />
      <property name="B" column="B_column" type="java.math.BigDecimal" />
      <property name="C" column="C_column" type="java.math.BigDecimal" />
      <property name="D" column="D_column" type="java.math.BigDecimal" />
      <property name="E" column="E_column" type="java.math.BigDecimal" />
      <property name="F" column="F_column" type="int" />
      <property name="G" column="G_column" type="java.sql.Timestamp" />
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

And my code is

```
List<Map<String, Object>> toBeSaved = getTransformedObjects();// all objects belong to same table
 Transaction tx = null;
 try (SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactoryFromXml(profile, job.getXmlMapping());// Creating Session from XML in my utils class
      Session session = factory.openSession()) {
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         toBeSaved.forEach(map -> {
            session.saveOrUpdate(job.getTableName(), map);
         });
         tx.commit();// Here exception occurs
       } catch (HibernateException e) {
         rollbackTransactionAndPrintException(e, destTx);
       }
```

Currently there is only one record in map and content of map is :

```
{
   datetime=2020-07-08 20:19:53.21, 
   F_column=1, 
   A_colummn=0.421, 
   G_column=2020-06-16 17:21:05.0, 
   code=TYUTQ, 
   B_column=0.000, 
   C_column=0.000, 
   D_column=50.540
}
```

i am using hibernate version `5.3.5.Final` and i am badly stuck in it.
Can anyone tell me how to resolve this ? Thanks in advance.